# How to take the screenshot in windows XP on virtualbox?

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, macbook-pro, screenshot

i have installed windows xp on macbook pro using virtual box. I need to take the screen shot. How to take this in windows xp on virtualbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way you take a screenshot in Windows is hit <kbd>PRINT</kbd>, paste the data into i.e. Paint and save the image. If you don't want the VirtualBox-Window to show, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to enable fullscreen mode and take the snapshot there.

Comment: On mac we don't have print button. what we do for this?

Comment: @bhakki Does this help? http://www.josiahland.com/archives/792

Answer (score 5):

You have to first release your keyboard from the VirtualBox window by pressing the Host Key (Right Ctrl by default). Then press Alt+Print Screen to capture just the window.

Answer (score 3):

The new feature is available in versions 4.0 and above, so this will not work on older editions of the software. What you need to do is invoke the following command:

```
VBoxManage controlvm <vm name> screenshotpng <filename>.png
```

That's the whole of magic, where  is the name of your virtual machine and  is any string you want to use to identify your screenshots later on.

Comment: Great find, thanks! Looks useful - in addition, this should probably work for *any* combination of VM host/VM guest.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use Skitch from my OS X host environment anytime I need to take a screenshot of something in a virtual machine.